# how to consumer this MQRFH2 message

Tags: ibm-mq

We want to upgrade MQ but we don't have the source code, the sender is generating a message `MQRFH2` but no parameters are displayed

But we also need to get the file name from message

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you explain more?  Do you have a program that already reads message with a RFH2 header that writes out a file?  Did this program stop working when you upgraded MQ?  Both screen shots look the same to me.  What shows up under the `MQRFH2 Properties` tab?

Comment: MQRFH2 no properties

Comment: The program of our environment is Windows, after upgrading, the program is not compatible.But the sending side can not upgrade.Now we want to rebuild the consumer side,However, we don't have the source code, we can see that it is RFH2 type. However, in the IBM Explorer, RFH2 properties is not displayed.Because these messages are in the message, I want to know whether I should process the message

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that the RFH2 is not supposed to be there and if there was some way to make it disappear so that you didn't have to change your code, that would be what you want?

Comment: It appears it is a empty RFH2 header, the filename looks like it is in the message body. You can specify `MQGMO_NO_PROPERTIES` to have your program ensure that that RFH2 header is not presented as part of the message body.  You can also use a Queue attribute `PROPCTL(NONE)` to accomplish the same thing.  You can also view this with the sample program `amqsbcg QUEUE.NAME QUEUEMANAGER 1`, the 1 at the end is important as this will tell it print out any properties included in the RFH2 and the data portion will have this removed, this way you can see if there is anything useful in the RFH2.

Comment: How do I get the file name if I remove the header?I want to know why this old program doesn't send RFH2 messages with parameters.command amqsbcg propoption is set to 1. any details about that?

Comment: @JoshMc   I change the default message properties in the ibm explorer.  Is it the same as amqsbcg？

Comment: I sorry to say I am not sure what you are looking to do.  I would like to see the output of the message when displayed with the `amqsbcg` command I provided, this will tell if the filename is a property in the RFH2 header.  It does not appear that it is.  It appears that it is just part of the message data.